# i have converted a 300w pc power supply into a bench top power supply

Tags: power-supply, power

why does the unit shut down when negative and positive touch.Is there a way to bypass this? I have heard turn it into a floating ground.

Comment: What else did you expect it to do?

Comment: if you disable that feature it will catch fire.

Comment: The best relevant link I found there is http://www.chirio.com/switching_power_supply_atx.htm  I will have to mod a few now with adjustable current limit.

Comment: thank you KalleMP this is along the lines of what i am trying to do i know it can be done because i have another power supply for tattoo machines witch connects negative and positive and runs continuously i need the feature because i am anodizing at home and want a better power supply than the battery charger i am using now

Comment: @ezigzag A better way to get your quesiton answer it 1)Write one that looks professional (use proper punctuation and grammar) 2) Learn how to write clear questions, your post should have a paragraph or two on your problem then clearly define your question(s) Thanks

Answer (score 2):

No. The power supply is shutting down due to a short on the output.